# LCOV code coverage - Exit status 255

Tags: gcov, lcov

When i run the code coverage to output in html, I get the error message:

CalledProcessError: Command 'lcov -r mycoverage.2.temp "/../generated/*" -o mycoverage.2' returned non-zero exit status 255

The gcov -v gives:
gcov (GCC) 3.4.2

I tried to find what exit status 255 means, but with no luck.

Any expert please who might be able to help?